# Why the offset value is not working if we set it equal to 1

Tags: node.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
var buf = new Buffer(1024);

console.log("Going to open an existing file");
fs.open('input.txt', 'r+', function(err, fd) {
   if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
   }
   console.log("File opened successfully!");
   console.log("Going to read the file");
   fs.read(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0, function(err, bytes){
      if (err){
         console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(bytes + " bytes read");

      // Print only read bytes to avoid junk.
      if(bytes > 0){
         console.log(buf.slice(0, bytes).toString());
      }
   });
});
```

if we set the value of offset equal 1 then why we get error??
[ fs.read(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0, function(err, bytes)]
in the following fuction

Comment: You should include the error in your question ...

Comment: Going to open an existing file
File opened successfully!
Going to read the file
fs.js:687
  binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, req);
          ^

RangeError: Length extends beyond buffer
    at RangeError (native)
    at Object.fs.read (fs.js:687:11)
    at C:\Users\admin\Desktop\node\e.js:11:7
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)